# Invalid Hook Call error: works on localhost but not with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-hooks

First I thought my React and React-dom were not in the same version. But I checked and they were all in the same version. The component itself renders and works properly in localhost, but when I test it using Jest it fails. Below is the error I get, and the location of error is in the .create method. Also, the tests pass when I don't pass in any child components. Both examples shown below. This is so confusing and I have no clue why the error is prompting. Any suggestions?

Edit: changed question format to show error better

To reproduce: `npm run test`

The Error

```
● Navbar component › Rendered navbar with 1 tab

    Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
    1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
    2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
    3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
    See fb.me/react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

      61 |   test('Rendered navbar with 1 tab', () => {
      62 |     const tree = renderer
    > 63 |       .create(
         |        ^
      64 |         <Navbar>
      65 |           <Navbar.Tab label="In Flight Orders" component={null} />
      66 |         </Navbar>

      at resolveDispatcher (../../../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1465:13)
      at Object.useState (../../../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1496:20)
      at useForceUpdate (../../../node_modules/framer-motion/dist/framer-motion.cjs.js:5707:33)
      at AnimatePresence (../../../node_modules/framer-motion/dist/framer-motion.cjs.js:5841:23)
      at renderWithHooks (../../node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:5552:18)
      at mountIndeterminateComponent (../../node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:7918:13)
      at beginWork (../../node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:9019:16)
      at performUnitOfWork (../../node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:12649:12)
      at workLoopSync (../../node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:12622:22)
      at performSyncWorkOnRoot (../../node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:12333:9)
      at ../../node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:1825:24
      at unstable_runWithPriority (../../node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:653:12)
      at runWithPriority (../../node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:1775:10)
      at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (../../node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:1820:7)
      at flushSyncCallbackQueue (../../node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:1808:3)
      at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (../../node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11776:9)
      at updateContainer (../../node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14747:3)
      at Object.create (../../node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15455:5)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/lib/navbar.spec.js:63:8)
```

This works

```
  test('Rendered navbar with many non tabs', () => {
    const tree = renderer
      .create(
        <Navbar>
          <h1>non tab 1</h1>
          <h1>non tab 2</h1>
        </Navbar>
      )
      .toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

This doesn't work

```
  test('Rendered navbar with filter', () => {
    const tree = renderer
      .create(
        <Navbar filter>
          <Navbar.Tab label="In Flight Orders" component={null} />
          <Navbar.Tab label="Active Service" component={null} />
          <Navbar.Tab label="Active Service 1" component={null} />
        </Navbar>
      ).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

Navbar.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import Tab from './tab';
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';
import { Arrow, ArrowGroup, Spacer, NavbarOutline, Content } from './styledNavbar';

const Navbar = ({children, filter}) => { ... }      

const Tabs = () => {                                
  return 'tabs';
};

Navbar.Tab = Tabs;

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Nothing that you posted suggests what the problem is. Basically it's either mismatching react/react-dom versions, or dupe packages, or the error refers to another place that really calls a hook outside a component. You truncated the error, call stack may contain debugging information.

Comment: `npm run test` can't reproduce the problem because there's no code to reproduce. The code is stripped down, it's unknown what's the difference between "This works" and "This doesn't work". There are `../../node_modules` and `../../../node_modules` at different levels, this suggests that there are nested projects, see the remark above about dupe packages.